# How to go to a new route by clicking in a button in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i'm a beginner  in Vuetify , and I'm develloping my first application, and my question is  :
 How by clicking on the "HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE" button in the navbar list the programm will route to a file called pass.vue (which is in the same folder ) ?

```
<template>
<div>
<v-toolbar
  dark
  prominent
  src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/backgrounds/vbanner.jpg"
>

<v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
<v-toolbar-title>Workers</v-toolbar-title>

</v-toolbar>



<v-navigation-drawer app 
v-model="drawer" 
 class="deep-purple accent-4"
absolute
  bottom
  temporary>
           <v-list
                nav
                dense
            >
                <v-list-item-group
                v-model="group"
                active-class="deep-purple--text text--accent-4"
                >
                <v-list-item>
                    <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-account</v-icon>
                    <router-view/>
                    </v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-list-item-title router:to="/pass.vue">HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>

                <v-list-item >
                    <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-help</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-list-item-title>Help</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>

                <v-list-item >
                    <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-alarm</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-list-item-title>Timetable</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>



                </v-list-item-group>
            </v-list>
</v-navigation-drawer>

</div>
</template>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I do it in this way, note that I use `:to` on `v-list-item` instead of `v-list-item-title`.

```
<v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.text" :to="item.link">
  <v-list-item-action>
    <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
  </v-list-item-action>
  <v-list-item-content>
    <v-list-item-title>
      {{ item.text }}
    </v-list-item-title>
  </v-list-item-content>
</v-list-item>
```

Example of `item.link`

```
// url
:to="/profile"

// path of Location obj
:to="{ path: '/profile' }"

// a more detail Location obj
:to="{ name: 'profile2', params: { userId: 123 }}"
```

You can either pass a string url to `:to` or a [Location](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-props). Make sure you've declare this route in your router like below:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/profile',
    name: 'profile',
    component: Profile
  },
  {
    path: '/profile2/:userId',
    name: 'profile2',
    component: Profile2
  }
];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but why we don't use directly the text .. instead of {{item.icon}}... and wherehave I to write the second part of your code ? I mean could you give an example where I have to write it please ?

Comment: As you can see I am using `v-for` looping an array to render the list, I have the icon defined in the array. And what do you mean second part of the code? What example you still looking for?

Comment: If you are asking about example in router, I have updated the answer, please have a look.

Comment: @– jet_choong Thank you for your answers , but I still have the same problem , even if I did the same as you(without using v-for but writing everything in it place)  it doesn't work ,  I specify that I created the router.js (I didn't find it even if I've installed vue-router) ,may be it's the problem ?

Comment: I believe you can get additional errors information by viewing browser developer console, please do that and provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you are confusing Vue with pure HTML. For Vue you need to use the Vue-Router library to create routes.
2. For Vuetify Components, or any components in general, remember that the `:to` creates a clickable link, so you would want to put it in a top level component which you want your user to click ex. `<v-list-item>` reather than `v-list-item-title`

Now for your particular case, your template should look like so:

```html
<v-list-item v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index" :to="{name: item.link}">
  <v-list-item-content>
    <v-list-item-title>
      {{ item.text }}
    </v-list-item-title>
  </v-list-item-content>
</v-list-item>
```

Followed by:

```js
...
data(){
 return{
  items:{
  text: 'HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE',
  link: 'pass' // this will be a named router link
 }
}
...
```

Now in a seperate file for your router, which if you add using the vue-cli (recommended) will be created and called `router.js`, add the following

```js
        {
            path: '/pass',
            name: 'pass', // same as passed in component
            component: () => import('@/path/to/file/pass.vue')
        }
```

Now, this ,ight be overwhelming at first, but it's actually very easy. I recommend you checkout [Vue-Router's Documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/) before you get back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of item title you can use `:to` in v-list-item and name must be same as defined in your routes.

```
        <v-list-item :to="{name:'pass'}">
          <v-list-item-title>HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
```