# I have problems when trying to route to a new page

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have problems when trying to route to a new page , I want to route to passe.js when clicking on "HEREEEEEEEEEEE" button , but it doesn't work ! note the pass.vue is in  "components" folder

```html
<template>
    <v-app>
        <div>
            <v-toolbar dark prominent src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/backgrounds/vbanner.jpg">

                <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
                <v-toolbar-title>Workers</v-toolbar-title>

            </v-toolbar>


            <div class="container d-flex flex-column">
                <v-container>
                    <v-row align="end" justify="end">
                        <v-btn x-large color="red">START</v-btn>>
                    </v-row>
                </v-container>
            </div>


            <v-navigation-drawer app v-model="drawer" class="primary" absolute bottom temporary>
                <v-list nav dense>
                    <v-list-item-group v-model="group" active-class="deep-purple--text text--accent-4">
                        <v-list-item :to=" 
        {name:'C:/Users/ykemi/OneDrive/Bureau/thermo/api/interface/th/src/components/pass.vue'}">
                            <v-list-item-icon>
                                <v-icon>mdi-account</v-icon>
                                <router-view />
                            </v-list-item-icon>
                            <v-list-item-title>HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item>
                        .
                        .

                    </v-list-item-group>
                </v-list>
            </v-navigation-drawer>

        </div>
    </v-app>
</template>


and followed by :

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
          drawer: false,
          group: null,
          theme:{
            primary:'#9652ff',
           }

        }),

        watch: {
          group () {
            this.drawer = false
          },
        },
      }
</script>
```

And this is the router.js that I've manually created because I didn't find it even if I've installed vue-router.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Pass from "C:/Users/ykemi/OneDrive/Bureau/thermo/api/interface/th/src/components/pass.vue";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/pass",
      name: "pass",
      component: Pass
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to go to a new route by clicking in a button in Vuetify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858645/how-to-go-to-a-new-route-by-clicking-in-a-button-in-vuetify)

Answer (score 1):

Vue can't detect when you click on an element until you assign an event listener to it.
Learn more about events here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

To instruct vue-router to go to a next page, you can either use a `router-link` or `router.push(href)`.
Learn more about navigating using vue-router here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

In your case, you want to execute the `$router.push` function upon `click` event.

So here is your code:

```html
<v-list-item-title @click="$router.push('/pass')"> ... </v-list-item-title>
```

Hope it helped

Comment: thaks , and I have to import router somewhere ? and what about the router.js in this case ?

Comment: @Joe yes, you have to define your routes in a router file: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/